# UITextView with links: how does VoiceOver select which link to tap?

Tags: ios, uitextview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `UITextView` with a paragraph of text, within the text there are two links (ie. via `addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: range)`). When I have VoiceOver turned on, I adjust the rotor to "Links", and after focusing on the `UITextView`, I can swipe up and down to refine the focus onto each of the links. However, this no longer works on iOS 13, I don't know what has been changed in this regard?

Thanks!

Comment: See this answer ⟹ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144836/3825084. I copied the code snippet in a blank project, followed the indications and it worked like a charm (iOS 13.5.1, iPhoneX, Xcode 11.5). Try directly from the device when the app is installed otherwise. 

Comment: I looked at the links and the instruction picture inside the link, my problem is I'm stuck on step 2, could not reach step 3, I'll give it another go anyway.