# iOS: Links do not appear on a rotor in Voice Over mode for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uitextview, voiceover

I use UITextView in my app. It contains a text and some URL links in it. I recognize the tap (double tap in Voice Over) on that UITextView and perform some action (overwriting default edit action).

When using the app in regular mode (Voice Over - off) the links are detectable and working (after a long tap on them).

When using the app in voiceOver mode the app does not detect URL links in that text view and does not enable activation of them.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39522364/14351818